# Como carregar imagens externas a um aplicativo do Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

Meu aplicativo usa a api do Imgur para hospedar imagens, mas na hora que vai carregar as fotos, aparece o seguinte erro:
[image: Erro]

Eu já tentei usar o `content_security_policy` no arquivo `manifest` mas aparece essa mensagem:
[image: Mensagem]

O que fazer?

Answer (score 2):

Tente atualizar o manifest.json do aplicativo com a a url que você quer acessar.

```
"permissions": ["storage", "webview", "<all_urls>"]
```

O `<all_urls>` tem o mesmo efeito que `http://*/*` ou `https://*/*` ou `*://*/*`. (Access your data on all websites).

Você pode tentar utilizar a permissão [webview](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview) também:

> Use the webview tag to actively load live content from the web over
>   the network and embed it in your Chrome App.

Se tiver alguma dúvida quanto aos "warnings" de permissões, acesse:

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permission_warnings

Comment: isso é o mesmo que "http://*/*", "https://*/*"? Por que já tem

Comment: atualizei a minha resposta ;)

Answer (score 2):

Se não me engano só é possível incluir urls que tenhas https, já criei uma extensão do chrome para calcular Ritmo de corrida que pode ser vista mo [link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/runner-tools/cmhlipamnbjichcdfbmhfaadneiafcai)

Você pode tentar também adicionar a permissão no manifest:

```
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://i.imgur.com 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
```

Comment: Está dando o mesmo erro pra imagem em https =/

Comment: Ajustei a resposta adicionando uma modificação possível no manifest.

Comment: Luis, se você olhar a pergunta, vai ver que o Chrome não aceita a opção "content_security_policy" =/